# What's the max number of retries in case of a continuously dropped SYN packet?

Tags: tcp

There's a product (that will stay unnamed) that suffers from a peculiar feature/issue.
It will drop new SYN packets if it is overloaded. This may not seem unreasonable to some. It may seem unthinkable to others. Be that as it may.

How many times will an upstream TCP client retry sending the SYN before giving up? Is this number based on a RFC or standard or is it just industry norm?

How about SCTP and INIT?

Comment: TCP generally uses a timeout, not a retry limit. The specifics are implementation dependent.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.


Comment: Thanks for the info about the timeout vs. retry limit. That was useful.

Comment: I also hear what you're saying about this not being about programming. That is a true statement. I figured this was about stacks like in TCP/SCTP stacks. Thanks for your response nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

1. The default TCP connect timeout, which is the underlying topic of your question, is platform-dependent at the client, somewhere around a minute. This is coded into the `connect()` system call as 3 retries using timeouts of say 8,16,32 seconds, depending on the implementation. The TCP stack may do its own retries as well before failing back to the `connect()` function, so there could be quite a few tries before the eventual `ECONNTIMEOUT.`
2. There is nothing wrong with a platform dropping SYN packets under overload. Unix has been doing it for thirty years, so it can't suddenly have become a problem now. It is a platform action, not a product action, so the secret unnamed product you mention is not the culprit, unless it is an operating system. I don't see why it can't be named here.

Comment: Thanks EJP. That was very useful. From searching around, I noticed that there's also a sysctl parameter on Linux called net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries that seems to drive this behavior.